# Error Trying to Test on Android Device - Meteor 1.6.1

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, sdk, command-line-interface

Trying to test Meteor's example to-do list app on my Android device, and got this error:

```
Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for Android.

Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites

Status of the individual requirements:
✓ Java JDK
✓ Android SDK
✗ Android target: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
  javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
  at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
  at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
  at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
  at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
  at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
  ... 5 more
✓ Gradle
```

I can't figure out how to fix it for the life of me. Here's what I've already tried:

- Fresh install of Android Studio
- Re-installed Android SDK 8.1 (Oreo) [API Level 27]
- Re-installed Android SDK Tools 26.1.1
- Re-installed Android Platform tools 27.0.1
- Installed Android Emulator 27.1.12
- Installed Android Support Repository
- Set ANDROID_HOME and added the
  tools directory to my PATH as specified on
  https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

Also note: I'm running macOS version 10.13.4 and Meteor 1.6.1

Any ideas for solutions? Has anyone else run into this problem?